# Liquibase Maven & Command line working differently

Tags: database, maven, liquibase

I have some changeLogs, when i run those from command line multiple times from liquibase command line script, it works pretty fine.

Everytime when i run liquibase:update, on the same ChangeLog it works and no warn is thrown

```
[www-data@ajeets database]$ liquibase --changeLogFile=changelog/changelog-install.xml update;
Liquibase Update Successful
[www-data@ajeets database]$ liquibase --changeLogFile=changelog/changelog-install.xml update;
Liquibase Update Successful
[www-data@ajeets database]$ liquibase --changeLogFile=changelog/changelog-install.xml update;
Liquibase Update Successful
[www-data@ajeets database]$
```

But when I run the same with maven setup, it throws error when i run 2nd time onwards, which seems to be right but why different behavior and is it possible to have same behavior actually in Maven too, as it is in command line, running everytime showing updated.

```
INFO 4/29/15 1:45 PM: liquibase: Executing: /home/www-data/workspace/database/src/main/resource/com/obolus/database/changelog/changelog-install.xml despite precondition failure due to onFail='WARN':
 Not executing changes in v000/master.xml
INFO 4/29/15 1:45 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock.
```

This warning is correct, but only thing is command line liquibase script never reports that, where as when i work with mvn and do mvn liquibase:update for the 2nd time onwards i get this.

Answer (score 0):

Okies, probably I got answer myself.

```
[www-data@ajeets resource]$ liquibase --changeLogFile=changelog-install.xml --logLevel=info update
INFO 4/29/15 3:22 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 4/29/15 3:22 PM: liquibase: Reading from LB_TEST.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 4/29/15 3:22 PM: liquibase: Executing: changelog-install.xml despite precondition failure due to onFail='WARN':
 Not executing changes in v000/master.xml
INFO 4/29/15 3:22 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Liquibase Update Successful
```

It's now showing the warning in command line as well. That was the trick of logLevel so i believe in command line by default the logLeve is set to "off" or "severe", but the only problem is i had the same logLevel in maven in property file and same property file was used in command line but it was not picked up.

Okies, I can live with it.